# hibernate creating empty table - hibernate_sequence at startup

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, sequences

So I just downloaded hibernate 5.0.0.1, and I tried my project to it, which is previously using hibernate 4.3.

When I insert to the database, it gives me this error:

> ERROR: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence

I am using mysql, and my generation strategy is set at GenerationType.auto, and it seems that now hibernate thinks using sequences is the best strategy for generating  values. But the table is empty. I think hibernate is atempting to get a value from the sequence but can't find any. But I'm confused because the hibernate_sequence is created by hibernate, shouldn't it provide an initial value?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The sequence table is because of how you've defined the primary key on one/all of your entities.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // or GenerationType.SEQUENCE
protected Long id;
```

If you want to use a table's identity column:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;
```

You might to check this thread for more information:
https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=999785&start=0

> @GeneratedValue JPA Annotation
>
> Quite often in these tutorials, we have used the @GeneratedValue
>   annotation to have thedatabase generate a unique primary key for us.
>   We have used the default Generation Type in each of our examples, but
>   there are actually four different strategies for having the primary
>   key generated by the database. Those four options are:
>
> AUTO IDENTITY TABLE SEQUENCE javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO
>
> The AUTO generation strategy is the default, and this setting simply
>   chooses the primary key generation strategy that is the default for
>   the database in question, which quite typically is IDENTITY, although
>   it might be TABLE or SEQUENCE depending upon how the database is
>   configured. The AUTO strategy is typically recommended, as it makes
>   your code and your applications most portable.
>
> javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY
>
> The IDENTITY option simply allows the database to generate a unique
>   primary key for your application. No sequence or table is used to
>   maintain the primary key information, but instead, the database will
>   just pick an appropriate, unique number for Hibernate to assign to the
>   primary key of the entity. With MySQL, the first lowest numbered
>   primary key available in the table in question is chosen, although
>   this behavior may differ from database to database.
>
> javax.persistence.GenerationType.Sequence
>
> Some database vendors support the use of a database sequence object
>   for maintaining primary keys. To use a sequence, you set the
>   GenerationType strategy to SEQUENCE, specify the name of the generator
>   annotation, and then provide the @SequenceGenerator annotation that
>   has attributes for defining both the name of the sequence annotation,
>   and the name of the actual sequence object in the database.

Comment: but my strategy is set to auto, and I think I would use what hibernate thinks is the best strategy. But how can I populate the sequence through hibernate?

Comment: The last item in the quote above says it all.  Honestly, don't use AUTO unless IDENTITY doesn't work for you.  Most databases support per-table unique identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL users:

`CREATE TABLE hibernate_sequence ( next_val BIGINT );`

And in case someone needs a Liquibase changeset:

```
<changeSet author="mate00" id="00">
    <createTable tableName="hibernate_sequence">
        <column name="next_val" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="true" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="mate00" id="01">
    <insert tableName="hibernate_sequence">
        <column name="next_val">1</column>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

It's good to insert an initial value of 1.

Comment: it works for me, after create table, run `insert hibernate_sequence (next_val) VALUES (0);` ref https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-message-could-not-read-a-hi-value-you-need-to-populate-the-table-hibernate_sequence/

Answer (score 1):

> Simple solution :

create hibernate_sequence table as :

```
"create sequence <schema/db>.hibernate_sequence"
```

Comment: MySQL does not support sequences

Answer (score 1):

It is Created because Hibernate using that table to track auto increment Id (Next Value of the ID)

Ex-

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do not create this entity, use in your configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
```